# Processing data streaming through kafka using Spark and programming in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, docker, apache-kafka

All in all I have to start by saying its been a bit of journey and this question probably requires you to have been where I am already. Okay diving in.

So I made a docker container with everything I need to submit jobs to spark (installed on this container), that are written in python. I kick them off with supervisor, pipe the console output to a log for troubleshooting purposes, and basically I want to run multiple scripts to account for multiple scenarios streaming into a single kafka topic.

Why do I want to do this? I am using Telegraf to collect metrics and sending all the metrics from multiple instances into a single topic in kafka named "telegraf". I know.... its very creative. Also, splitting up the topics based on a given instance is irrelevant right now because all the different metrics come in for each instance so I still gotta process them differently.

Anyways so to give you an example, Telegraf collects some docker stats I want, two of which are "docker_container_cpu" and "docker_container_mem". Now My current solution is to have my script process the metric data differently based on the metric that is coming in. However, what I want to do is write lots and lots of scripts to each account for different scenarios that may be streaming into kafka. So one script for docker_container_cpu and another for docker_container_mem. Both of these would be listening to the kafka topic, both jobs submitted and running simultaneously.

```
command=bash -c "spark-submit --jars $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-streaming_2.11-$SPARK_VERSION.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-$SPARK_VERSION.jar $SPARK_HOME/scripts/aggregateCPU.py localhost:32181 telegraf &> $SPARK_HOME/logs/cpu.log &"

command=bash -c " sleep 30s; spark-submit --jars $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-streaming_2.11-$SPARK_VERSION.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-$SPARK_VERSION.jar $SPARK_HOME/scripts/aggregateMem.py localhost:32181 telegraf &> $SPARK_HOME/logs/mem.log &"
```

So whats the problem you ask?

This.....

```
    bash-4.3# cat logs/mem.log
17/08/02 19:31:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/08/02 19:32:02 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/08/02 19:32:02 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
17/08/02 19:32:02 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Attempting port 4043.
17/08/02 19:32:02 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4043. Attempting port 4044.
```

I get these errors whenever I try to submit both jobs.

So... In case you are wondering how you might reproduce my code, here is the snippet you will find relevant.

```
def setupKafkaStream():
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, brokers, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
kvs.foreachRDD(handler)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
return kafkaStream
```

Both scripts create the "Spark Streaming Context" so obviously this is a problem. I just don't know why yet. I want to utilize the power of spark cluster processing for all these metrics so my plan was to have multiple scripts subscribing to the relevant topic and then spark could split up the job as it sees fit.

I'm wondering if I am limited to one "Spark Streaming Context" or if this thing is as powerful as I thought.

PS: if any spark maintainers are listening, thank you for rewriting the whole library in scala, now lets make a bigger leap and rewrite it all using python. :) we love python. Java, no matter how a big a facelift (eh hmm... scala), is slow in comparison.

Comment: actually Python is/should be slower than Java, unless in specific cases where you're running in PyPy (this assumes that your application stays up long enough to compensate for jvm startup time). According to [Fail to create SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662084/fail-to-create-sparkcontext) you should create a single Spark Context and each SC can have multiple streaming contexts.

Comment: @cowbert they were running in spark-shell. I am submitting this job to spark so I wouldn't think the SparkContext would be shared.

Comment: @cowbert gave it a shot anyways and it was a no go. There wasn't any recognized syntax for conf = new SparkConf() with the error marker set at "new". Must be something else. I was wondering about the port though. Do you know how to specify the ui.port?